# Does a water bottle become fleishig from a meal?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, meat-and-milk, water

If I drank from a water bottle during a meat meal, does it become meat?

Basically, if I drink from the same water bottle a few hours later, do I need to wait six hours again?

Comment: What is the bottle made out of?  (Plastic I assume, but more specifically?)

Comment: The short answer is: no.

Comment: (Unless of course you were drinking pieces of meat, in which case: maybe.)

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Note also that this site makes no guarantee of validity, and does not offer professional (particularly rabbinic) advice. Treat information from this site like it came from a crowd of your friends. For a definitive ruling, please contact your rabbi. You might also want to see "[Why is it necessary to ask a rabbi?](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146)" for more info. We hope to see you around!

Answer (score 2):

If you got meat oil on the bottle it could become "a fleishig bottle", or b'cheskas fleishig, under some circumstances. Though eating something pareve from a meat dish never requires you to wait 6 hours. so if you later drank water from it, you would not have to wait. the only issue would be whether or not you could put milk in it and drink from it.

Even cooking something pareve in a meat pan, won't necessarily render it fleishig, rather whats called in halachah "b'cheskas fleishig". Which basically means, you can't eat it together with milk, but you don't have to wait after either.

Comment: Providing sources and / or links would make this answer stronger.

Answer (score 0):

**There is no need to wait six hours after drinking from that bottle to eat milk** but there would be an issue in drinking from that same bottle during a milk meal.

See dinonline's [answer](https://en.dinonline.org/2016/12/01/drinking-out-of-a-plastic-bottle-during-a-milk-meal-when-it-was-used-for-a-meat/) to a very similar question

> During the milky meal he should not drink from the bottle, since there
> is residue from the meat meal in and on the bottle. After the meal
> however he may drink from it, however it is preferable to wash it out
> first.

See sources [there](https://en.dinonline.org/2016/12/01/drinking-out-of-a-plastic-bottle-during-a-milk-meal-when-it-was-used-for-a-meat/).